# Корректно собрать apk пакет. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: java, android, apk

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. У меня видимо не получается корректно собрать apk пакет для андроида на Java.
Собирается без ошибок, в эмуляторе запускается отлично, в БлюСтакс тоже работает.
Но на телефоне вечно пишет "Приложение не установлено". Видимо дело в моей корявой сборке.

Вот мой проект на Гите [Проект на ГитХаб](https://github.com/AntsupovAlex/List)

Если возможно - помогите. Не понимаю в чем дело.

Comment: а вы какую версию собираете - релизную или дебажную? проблема может быть в этом

Comment: Вначале собирал дебаг. Не знал, что надо релиз. Потом начал читать мануалы - переставил вид сборки на release. Но проблема осталась

Comment: вы пробовали подключить телефон к пк и установить на него напрямую, или вы так и устанавливаете?

Comment: Делаю на работе, поэтому скинул через рабочую почту на свою, скачал оттуда на телефон и пытался устанавливать.

Comment: попробуйте подключить телефон через шнурок и установить напрямую, так будет проще и понятнее что не так, может у вас на телефоне запрещена установка из неизвестных источников например?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Такие возможности я исключил. На телефоне я в категории "Безопасность" поставил режим для любых источников. В Плэй Маркете убрал Плэй защиту. Клин Мастером вычистил всю систему - свободно 1,5 Гига (приложение весит 1,34 метра). Делал перезагрузки после данных операций. Перечитал кучу материалов. Но проблема осталась на месте. Теперь сижу в замешательстве.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102557/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and--).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данная проблема вызвана тем что вы не отмечаете не все необходимые параметры при создании подписанного приложения. При создании у вас есть такое окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вам нужно отметить не только **V2 (Full APK Signature)** но и **V1 (Jar Signature)**. Именно в таком виде вы сможете без проблем установить приложение на поддерживаемые устройства.